# Overlaying MATLAB Scaled Image to Grayscale Image for selected pixels

Tags: image, matlab, overlay, grayscale

I am new to MATLAB Image Processing and currently I have two images - one is a grayscale image of my object and the second is the scaled image generated from MATLAB using imagesc function. I am trying to overlay this scaled image on top of my grayscale image to get a spatial resolution for easier observation. Attached are the two images:

A) Grayscale Image:

[image: grayscale image]

B) Scaled Image:
[image: scaled image]

There were a few difficulties that I encountered. Firstly, the scaled image is not saved in the same pixel dimensions, but I can get around that using the imwrite function:

```
im = imagesc(ScaledDiff);
imwrite(get(im,'cdata'),'scaleddiff.tif')
```

However, doing so will result in a loss of colorbar and the colormap. Secondly, even if I manage to shrink the scaled image to the size of the grayscale image, overlaying it is still a challenge. Ideally, I would like to set the transparency (or 'alpha') to 0 for those pixels with < 0.02 in scaled image value.

Any idea on how to do this will be greatly appreciated! Sorry if I was unclear!

---

UPDATE:
Thanks to Rotem, I have managed to overlay the grayscale image and a particular region of my heatmap:

[image: overlay]

However, I need to display the colorbar corresponding to the heatmap values, because otherwise the information is lost and the overlay will be useless. How should I do this? Below is a snippet of my code, where ScaledIntDiff contains the values from 0 to 0.25 that is displayed on the heatmap:

```
Brightfield = imread('gray.jpg'); % read background image
I1 = ind2rgb(gray2ind(Brightfield), gray); % convert indices into RGB scale

scale = 1000;
ScaledIntDiff2 = round(ScaledIntDiff.*scale); 
I2 = ind2rgb(ScaledIntDiff2, jet(256)); % this is for the heatmap

threshold = 0.02;
I2R = I2(:,:,1); I2G = I2(:,:,2); I2B = I2(:,:,3);
I1R = I1(:,:,1); I1G = I1(:,:,2); I1B = I1(:,:,3);
% Replace pixels in I2 with pixels in I1 if the value of ScaledIntDiff of those pixels is below the threshold
I2R(ScaledIntDiff<threshold) = I1R([ScaledIntDiff<threshold]);
I2G(ScaledIntDiff<threshold) = I1G([ScaledIntDiff<threshold]);
I2B(ScaledIntDiff<threshold) = I1B([ScaledIntDiff<threshold]);
I2(:,:,1) = I2R; I2(:,:,2) = I2G; I2(:,:,3) = I2B;

figure
imshow(I2)
```

I know that the code above is highly inefficient, so suggestions on how to improve it will be very welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: First recommendation: Don't use `imagesc`, create RGB image using `ind2rgb`. Example: `I = imread('cameraman.tif');J = ind2rgb(I, parula(256));imshow(J)`.

Comment: In case you still need to resize the image, use: `imresize`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

```
I = imread('CKbi2Ll.jpg'); %Load input.

%Convert I to true color RGB image (all pixels R=G=B are gray color).
I1 = ind2rgb(I, gray(256));

%Convert I to true color RGB image with color map parula (instead of using imagesc)
I2 = ind2rgb(I, parula(256));

%Set the transparency (or 'alpha') to 0 for those pixels with < 0.02 in scaled image value.
%Instead of setting transparency, replace pixels with values from I1.
threshold = 0.02; %Set threshold to 0.02
I2(I1 < threshold) =  I1(I1 < threshold);

%Blend I1 and I2 into J.
alpha = 0.3; %Take 0.3 from I2 and 0.7 from I1.
J = I2*alpha + I1*(1-alpha);

%Display output
imshow(J);
```

[image]

---

Adding a `colorbar` with ticks labels from 0 to 0.25:

- Set color map to `parula` - it doesn't affect the displayed image, because image format is true color RGB.
- Crate array of add 6 ticks from 0 to 250.
- Create cell array of 6 `TickLabels` from 0 to 0.25.
- Add `colorbar` with `Ticks` and `TickLabels` properties created earlier.

Add the following code after `imshow(J);`:

```
colormap(parula(256));
TLabels = cellstr(num2str((linspace(0, 0.25, 6))'));
T = linspace(1, 250, 6);
colorbar('Ticks', T', 'TickLabels', TLabels);
```

[image]

---

```
imshow('ClmypzU.jpg');
colormap(jet(256));
TLabels = cellstr(num2str((linspace(0, 0.25, 6))'));
T = linspace(1, 250, 6);
colorbar('Ticks', T', 'TickLabels', TLabels);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works but I need to display the colorbar to show the values above (0 to 0.25). Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean showing only the lower 25% of the `parula` colormap in a colorbar?

Comment: `colorbar;` `cm = parula(256);` `cm = cm(1:64, :);` `colormap(cm);`

Comment: In case it's not what you meant, post a new question. Make the question minimal (ask specifically about showing a colorbar). Be more clear of what you mean by "display the colorbar to show the values above (0 to 0.25)".

Comment: That's not what I meant. If you look at my original post, under "B) Scaled Image:", you can see the colorbar on the right side of the picture ranging from 0 to 0.25. I would like to show this next to the overlay image. I did mention this in my original post that I would like to keep the colorbar, hence I did not post a new question.

Comment: Just setting the ticks labels of the `colorbar`? It makes the colorbar unrelated to the displayed image...

Comment: I think I did not explain my case clearly, my bad, so I have updated the original post to describe what I am trying to achieve. The colorbar I was referring to will correspond only to the heatmap, not the grayscale background image, so that reader will know what the heatmap color refers to.

Comment: Can't you just replace the `parula` colormap in my example with `jet` colormap?

Comment: That works for this example, but I still have to set the range of the scale manually from 0 to 0.25. I would like to automate the colorbar because the values may change in different situations, e.g. from 0 to 0.40.